# SKShapeNode set SKAction to scale from center

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a Tile class which is a subclass of SKShapeNode

```
@interface Tile : SKShapeNode
```

and I instantiate the class as follows:

```
//  Tile.h
-(instancetype) addHiddenTileToSpace:(NSString *)letter withIndex:(int)i withPositionInWord:(int)p;
```

In my implementation file I have

```
//  Tile.m
-(instancetype) addHiddenTileToSpace:(NSString *)letter withIndex:(int)i withPositionInWord:(int)p{
if(self == [super init] ){
    self.name = @"Tile";
   // self.hidden = YES;
    if (p == 0) {
        self.firstLetter = YES;
    }
    else{
        self.firstLetter = NO;
    }
    self.positionInAnswer = i;
    self.character = letter;

    [self setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60), 4, 4, nil)];
    self.strokeColor = self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0f/255.0f
                                                        green:74.0f/255.0f
                                                         blue:84.0f/255.0f
                                                        alpha:1];
    SKLabelNode *characterNode = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Avenir-Medium"];
    characterNode.text = [letter uppercaseString];
    characterNode.fontSize = 40;
    characterNode.fontColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f
                                              green:216.0f/255.0f
                                               blue:216.0f/255.0f
                                              alpha:1];
    characterNode.position = CGPointMake(30, 15);
    [self addChild:characterNode];
}
return self;
```

}

The problem is that I want to animate/scale that node but it scales from the coordinates (0,0) of the node rather than scaling from it's center.  I have read elsewhere that I should use the `+ (instancetype)shapeNodeWithPath:(CGPathRef)path
                         centered:(BOOL)centered` method and set the center to YES

However in my method above instantiating the I'm not sure how to initialise the SKSHapeNode using the shapeNodeWithPath method. or is there some other way that I can set the Tile.center = YES;

Comment: Why are you using a SKShapeNode for a simple tile?

Answer (score 1):

I think where you draw your shape will fix your issues. You are drawing from 0,0 which would be the center of the node and it looks like you are positioning the label also to compensate for this. Something like this might help.

```
...
[self setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-30, -30, 60, 60), 4, 4, nil)];
//or it could be [self setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-30, 30, 60, 60), 4, 4, nil)];
...
characterNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 15);
...
```

Now when you scale everything should actually be in the center of the node instead off offset by 30. I haven't tested this theory, but it should fix positioning and scaling issues.

Good luck and hope that helps.